# Does Google Hangout support new email notifications like Google Talk?

Tags: email, notifications, google-talk

Does Google Hangout support new email notifications like Google Talk? Because Google Talk is able to inform me when I receive new email on gmail (notification in system tray) - is this possible with Google Hangout installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it's not possible in the Hangout client.

I believe this is now replaced by Desktop Notification supported by Gmail itself.

[This is the setting you want](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/1075549?hl=en)

EDIT: You need to keep chrome open for Desktop Notification to work. You may want to stick with Talk if this is not what you want.

Comment: Thank you for your answer about Hangout client. To "Desktop Notification supported by Gmail": Chrome has to be opened, so it is not what I want. I asked this question because I read that Hangout is the "replacement" of Talk - so I thought it supports everything what Talk does and even more - but this does not seem to be the case. I thought, that Talk is then obsolete and I should use Hangout instead of it. So I will still stick with Talk.

Comment: I would like to mark your answer as accepted but have to edit it that I still should use Talk (instead of "Desktop Notification supported by Gamil itself", as you wrote).

Comment: In Chrome's settings, you can turn on "Continue running background apps when Google Chrome is closed". Notifications should work, because Chrome is never really closed when this setting is on.